# My SKTexture is size wrong for my SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite, skspritenode, sktexture

I have a 200 x 100 box-like menu button SKSpriteNode declared below.

```
menuBtn.size = CGSize(width: scrWidth * 1.5, height: 100)
menuBtn.texture = SKTexture(image: UIImage(named: "menuBtn")!)
```

The problem is, the hitbox for the button is still right, and the width of the SKTexture is fine, but the height of the SKTexture is around 1/2 the size of the actual menuBtn. It is a png, and I've checked and there's no clear textures around the sprite (just the transparent png ones), what am I doing wrong?

Pic of button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJhYg.jpg

Pic of button in App: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z12eE.jpg

Pic of how I want it to look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQL8h.jpg

The texture's png image size is 1044x1044 if that has any impact.

Comment: Can you show a picture of everything you mentioned?

Comment: What are the dimensions of the png?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon sure i'll add an imgur link

Comment: @LouFranco Idk, how do I check that?

Comment: What is scrWidth

Comment: Look at the info for the png in the Finder. The `file` command line utility will also work; `file path/to/file.png`

Comment: seems to be 1044x1044

Comment: @Knight0fDragon the screen width `scrWidth = self.size.width / 2` I use it in order to set up some componenets in my app

Comment: well that is your problem.  Your menu is not correctly proportional.  It is not cutting in half, you are just on a device that offers more vertical space.  1st thing is your menu should not be a square size, you have a lot of space.  2nd thing is you need to account for where the bottom of the screen is on all devices, and offset based on that.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon The problem when I do that is that there's a lot of extra black space on the sides and top depending on the device if I do .aspectFit, and .aspectFill causes everything to become too large. To clarify, self in that case = gameSC (the gameScene)

Comment: that is because you are not properly using SpriteKit (I am going to assume one of many very bad tutorials).  It goes beyond the scope of this question unfortunately.  The basics of SpriteKit, is you only need to design for 1 size, and account for various aspect ratios.  99% of the time I recommend using a square scene to allow for wide and tall devices. For things like your menu button.  Do not even use SpriteKit.  Use UIKit, and make it a sub view of the SKView.  This removes all unnecessary nodes from SpriteKit evaluation.

Comment: Is there a simple temp. fix for my menu button problem? It's literally the only thing I'd have to resize. Also where can I learn the "basics" of SpriteKit easy + free?

Comment: Yes.... remove the transparency from your menu button

Comment: How do I remove the transparency from my menu button?

Comment: Photoshop, gimp, MSPaint...... whatever you need to not make it a square 1044x1044 texture

Comment: Ok, thanks, I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had was that there were extra transparent pixels in my base image, all I had to do was remove them with GIMP.

Comment: We kinda figured that out when we asked you to show us the png file. 

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the help, but I couldn't give the "answer" to a comment, and if anyone else had this question they'd be confused.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you are sending the correct size to your scene from `GameViewController` to your scene, in this example `GameScene`.

```
// without .sks

class GameViewController: UIViewController 
{
    override func viewDidLoad() 
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // ...        

        if let view = self.view as! SKView?
        {
            let scene = GameScene()

            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit

            // Set anchorPoint and pass scene.size
            scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
            scene.size = view.bounds.size

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

        // ...
}

// with .sks

class GameViewController: UIViewController 
{
    override func viewDidLoad() 
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // ...   

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? 
        {
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene.sks") 
            {
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit

                // Pass scene.size
                scene.size = view.bounds.size

                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)
            } 
        }

        // ...
}
```

In your `GameScene` create the object. I recommend working in `screenWidth` and `screenHeight` when you create objects so they scale to all iOS devices.

```
class GameScene: SKScene 
{
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) 
    {
        // ...

        // scene width / height
        let sceneWidth = size.width
        let sceneHeight = size.height

        // object
        let menu : SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
        menu.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "menu")
        menu.size = CGSize(width: sceneWidth * 0.75, height: 100)
        let y_pos : CGFloat = -sceneHeight * 0.5 + menu.size.height * 0.5
        menu.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: y_pos)
        menu.zPosition = 1
        addChild(menu)

        // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: `menuBtn = self.childNode(withName: "menuBtn") as! SKSpriteNode
        menuBtn.size = CGSize(width: scrWidth * 1.5, height: 100)
        menuBtn.color = UIColor(ciColor: .blue)
        menuBtn.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -scrHeight + safeArea.bottom + 50)
        menuBtn.zPosition = 2
        menuBtn.texture = SKTexture(image: UIImage(named: "menuBtn")!)` is how I declared my object (since it was already in the sks), but it seems to basically be the same. All my aspects scale the same to all devices, but this button has its texture shrink for just its y value. That's what I was asking.

Comment: Can you add a link to the menu image? the menuBtn one.

Comment: You should not be setting your scene to your view size, this goes against the very basis of Spritekit's scaling feature.  SpriteKit is designed in a way where you only need to design in 1 size, and you let the hardware do the rest

Comment: The problem when I do that is that there's a lot of extra black space on the sides and top depending on the device if I do .aspectFit, and .aspectFill causes everything to become too large.